# SGE Cluster qsub email notifications not working

Tags: email, sungridengine, qsub

I'm working on an SGE cluster and having some problems with the qsub email notification system.  All of my jobs work perfectly, but I seem unable to modify the default behaviour to only notify at an aborted job.  The -M flag works correctly, and I do receive an email when the job is aborted, however I would like to get an email when a job begins, ends, is aborted, or suspended.  I am using the following flags (and more) in my scripts, is there something stupid that I am missing?

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -M email@server
#$ -m beas

program
```

It also does not work when I try the following:

```
qsub -M email@server -m baes script.sh
```

Is this an issue that I should take up with my cluster sys admins, or have I done something incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to understand in solving this problem is that your job status email will be sent by the node where the job runs.  For example, I have a test job with the following output:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#$ -N MAIL
#$ -j y
#$ -m easb
#$ -M pkenyon

hostname
```

Now, run the job, and see where it ran.

```
[pkenyon@head ~]$ qsub mail.sh
Your job 346 ("MAIL") has been submitted
[pkenyon@head ~]$ cat MAIL.o346
node03.cluster
```

If you look at the mail logs on the system, you'll see the delivery attempts made.  You'll have to diagnose from there.  Here are a few examples for failures (or even successes that aren't successful in the way you want them to be):

- Sent to the compute node address, using `-M pkenyon`

  ```
  ...
  Jun  5 13:56:00 node04 postfix/local[13141]: 14A3E143320: to=<pkenyon@node04.cluster>, orig_to=<pkenyon>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
  ...
  ```
- Head node MX not set up right, using `-M pkenyon@head.cluster`

  ```
  ...
  Jun  5 14:00:30 node04 postfix/smtp[13283]: 35CC4143320: to=<pkenyon@head.cluster>, relay=none, delay=0.36, delays=0.17/0/0.19/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=head.cluster type=AAAA: Host not found)
  ...
  ```
- You need to set up your system to use a local mail relay if using `-M someone@gmail.com`

  ```
  ...
  Jun  5 12:20:47 node04 postfix/smtp[12798]: 1EEA5143320: to=<someone@gmail.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[64.233.168.27]:25, delay=0.64, delays=0.04/0/0.59/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[64.233.168.27] said: 550 Relay not permitted (in reply to RCPT TO command))
  ...
  ```

So yes, you need to talk to your cluster sysadmins, but these are the first steps to figuring out where your SGE emails are hanging up.  With a little more information, your admins will be able to fix the configuration issue and help you get more out of your cluster environment.

Comment: Great advice Paul, this will definitely give me something to work with.